# Fixed header and footer outside scrollview

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a grid that has a header, content and a footer:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/> <!--HEADER-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!--CONTENT-->
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/> <!--FOOTER-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Rectangle>
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Grid>
    ...
    </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>
 <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

I want to have it so that the header and footer are fixed and the content is scrollable. Within the second nested grid there is a lot of content, hence the scroll view. When I run the application, the scrollviewer still scrolls with the header and footer! I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, is there a better layout I should be using?

Please let me know! I'd rather not use C#.

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you don't have another ScrollView around that Grid. That is the only reason for such behavior, since ScrollViews body can be of any size that's why that inner one wouldn't scroll.

Comment: But you would notice it, since that second ScrollView can't scroll, when you hold mouse inside the inner one.

Comment: I do have a second scroll view inside the grid, but when I remove it I still have the same problem.

Comment: Use WPF Inspector to figure out what is actually happening there. You will have a problem downloading it though from original codeplex page. In downloaded archive is releases folder. Naming is obscure, but json file contains right names.
You could use VS's live tree, but it is not that simple as Ctrl clicking with WPF Inspector on any control. +It shows Style stack and triggers and previews... Really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are doing something strange either around the XAML you have posted or inside the nested `Grid` object, your XAML works as you intended.
I very slightly modified your XAML, just to visibly show your header and footer, and to add some content to your inner grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="55"/><!--HEADER-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/><!--CONTENT-->
    <RowDefinition Height="55"/><!--FOOTER-->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="55" Fill="Red"/>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Grid >
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItems, FallbackValue='123456789abcdefghijklmno'}"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
<Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="55" Fill="Blue"/>
</Grid>
```

Shown below is the result.  Your `ScrollViewer` scrolls just fine while leaving the header and footer in place.
I'm not sure what else you have going on in your window, but this is the only XAML in the window I used for testing, and it works perfectly.  As a note, I limited the height of the window to '400' so the inner grid did not continue to grow since it's height was set to `*`.  You can achieve the same result by setting a maximum height on your outer `Grid`.

[image]

Comment: Same thing here, I did not find any problems. Only if you encompass all that thing in another ScrollViewer then that thing happens, and only then.